# I have troubles with this simple OOP exercise (C#/Java)

Tags: java, c#, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

Given this piece of code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    C c = new A();
    B bl = (B)(new A());
    B b2 = new D();
    A a = new D();
}
```

I was required to determine the relationships between the classes, based on the given code, and pick the correct answer from the list below:

1. C inherits from A, B inherits from A, D inherits from A.
2. A inherits from C, B inherits from A, D inherits from A.
3. C inherits from A, B inherits from A, D inherits from B.
4. A inherits from C, C inherits from B, D inherits from A.
5. A inherits from C, B inherits from A, D inherits from B,
   C inherits from B.

From the first line I determined that A inherits from C (due to the upcasting) which eliminated options 1 and 3.

The second line was somewhat problematic to me. I don't know if I'm correct, but I used it to conclude that A does not inherit from B, because otherwise the casting wouldn't have been necessary.

From the third line I determined that D inherits from B, and from the fourth that D inherits from A as well.

According to some website which had answers to this question, the correct answer is option 4. This I understand, because this is the only option which partially contains the conclusions I arrived at, while the rest contain obvious errors or unsupported claims. What I DON'T understand is, why does C inherit from B? (according to option 4). I did not manage to conclude that from anywhere in the code.

Why is that true? Help will be much appreciated :)

Comment: Indeed, there´s nothing that would yield to that conclusion. `C` could also be the base-class of `B`.

Comment: `B` could be an interface.

Comment: According to the details provided in the textbook, B is a class.

Comment: Try writing the actual classes to test it and see where that differs from your expectation. This appears to just require arguing about code using knowledge you already have, and which can also easily be figured out by writing some code, which doesn't make for the most useful of questions.

Comment: This seems less like what can you infer than a which of the following can be true as it does not tell you the direct relationship between C and B.

Comment: A inherits from B, otherwise casting would fail. This automatically means 4 is the correct answer, because it is the only one who doesn't have the condition "B inherits from A". To be honest, I would never give such a question on test or anywhere, where guessing the correct answer requires solving only one of the conditions.

Comment: "why does C inherit from B?". It doesn't have to. You were correct in your decision making. The question is flawed in that there are two possibilities. #4. is only correct (if you want to call it correct) because the other possible answer was not listed and the others fail the conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because casting isn't necessary doesn't mean you can spell it out explicitly.  You're right - technically you don't need the (B) in:

```
B bl = (B)(new A());
```

Anyways, getting this dependency tree isn't necessarily simple.  Here's all you really know:

1. A is the child/grandchild/etc of C
2. A is the child/grandchild/etc of B
3. D is the child/grandchild/etc of B
4. D is the child/grandchild/etc of A

It's very important to realize that just because you know that A inherits from C does *not* mean that A is the direct child of C.  There could be other classes between them in the inheritance chart.

Assuming there aren't any other classes (for all you know, there's a Class 'E' that's between any of those two classes), there are actually two ways to chart it - there's not enough info to tell which it is.

**Option A: C is the Base Class**

C is the base class - there's no reason it can't, because it doesn't derive from anything else.  A has to derive from both B and C, so B must be up the tree between A and C.  Likewise, D derives from A, making it one long chain:

```
    public class A : B { }
    public class B : C { }
    public class C { }
    public class D : A { }
```

**Option B: B is the Base Class.**

B is the base class.  After all, it doesn't derive from anything, so there's no reason it can't be.  Similar to the first option, A has to derive from both B and C, which means C is directly up the chain between A and B.  And also similarly, D derives from A, so it goes at the bottom of a long chain.

```
    public class A : C { }
    public class B { }
    public class C : B { }
    public class D : A { }
```

So, when it's all said and done:

- A: Inherits from both B and C
- B: Possibly inherits from C
- C: Possibly inherits from B
- D: Inherits from A, B, and C

Answer (score 0):

The dependency tree would look like (starting from top-most class), based on 4th answer:

`B->C->A->D`, which breaks down to:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    C c = new A();       // C->A       (direct parent)
    B bl = (B)(new A()); // B->C->A    (2 levels up), casting to B can be avoided
    B b2 = new D();      // B->C->A->D (3 levels up)
    A a = new D();       // A->D       (direct parent)
}
```

That is the only option, among presented once,  that works with all lines of code, with no exception.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how did you get to the conclusion in the second line?

Comment: @Blabla: `B` is a base class of `A`.

Comment: @Tigran That that doesn't necessarily mean B is a base class of C.  The reason the correct answer is correct is just because it's the only one that fits.

Comment: @juharr: I've never said that for that line of code, that is the only possible explanation. The question was, why 4th answer is correct one for code provided, so my answer targets explanation of why it satisfies all code conditions in example provided.